# Dropdown menu not closing jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong, if you click on the first link(link 1) it opens a menu, if you click on one of the 'li' inside the menu it closes the menu.

If I click on the second link(link 2) it opens a different menu but when I click on one of the 'li' inside the menu nothing happens, and what I am trying to do is to close the menu.

jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/BdhxL/)

The HTML code:

```
<a href="#">Link 1</a> 
        <div id="dropMenu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#index">Portfolio</a></li> 
          </ul> 
        </div>
 <br><br>   
    <a href="#">Link 2</a> 
        <div id="dropMenu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#index">Contact us </a></li> 
          </ul> 
        </div>
```

The JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li").click(function()
  {
    $("#dropMenu").hide("slow");
  });

  $("a").click(function()
  {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(this).next("div").stop('true','true').slideToggle("slow");
  });
});

 #dropMenu {
    display: none; 
    position: relative; 
    right: 5px; 
    background: #000; 
    color: black; 
    margin:50px -5% 0% -142%;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px; 
}

#dropMenu a { 
    display: block; 
    color: #fff; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    padding:10px 6px;
    font-weight:400;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #fff;

}
```

The CSS code:

```
#dropMenu ul {
    margin:0;
}

#dropMenu a:hover { 
    background: #57585A; 
}

#dropMenu ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have duplicate ids.`$("#dropMenu").hide("slow");` is always targetting first dropMenu. Use `$(this)` to target current and hide the closest div.Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("li").click(function()
 {
  $(this).closest("div").hide("slow");
});

 $("a").click(function()
 {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  $(this).next("div").stop('true','true').slideToggle("slow");
});});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BdhxL/4/)**

Comment: Thanks for you help, but the problem with this solution is that you can only open one time the menu, if you close the menu theres no way to open it again

Comment: @CarlosPerez:upadted answer.check now.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you're having duplicated `id` for parent div of your list which is `<div id="dropMenu">` , you need to use class instead:

```
<div class="dropMenu">
```

then you can use **[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)** to target closest matching `.dropMenu` of clicked `li`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li").click(function () {
        $(this).closest(".dropMenu").hide("slow");
    });

    $("a").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(this).next("div").stop('true', 'true').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

You also need to change all `#dropMenu` to  `.dropMenu` in your CSS.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BdhxL/1/)**